# css padding top not working in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, margin

I am trying to build a navigation that works great in firefox but in chrome the padding top does not work, here is my link:

http://yesiamprimary.com/heather/

can anyone help me determine how to get this working in Chrome.

Comment: Can you include some code in your post?

Comment: please include code in your post for the sake of future visitors

Comment: padding works fine in Chrome 26.0.1410.43 On Mac OSX 10.8.3

Comment: @Alpdog14: Are you okay with the line being above the blocks or did you want it behind them?

Comment: Your pages look identical in chrome and firefox. What padding exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: i applied the display:block and it worked, the issue i am having now is the small 1px line of color appearing below each button, i cannot seem to get rid of that

Comment: Seems that adding the display:block on the "a" in the css, is causing this small 1px padding at the bottom, how do i get rid of that

Comment: I fixed it with line-height:18px